# Could a planetary object spin at (or near )the speed of light?

Tags: physics, astrophysics

And if so, what would it look like to an observer on the planet and an observer in orbit around the planet?

Comment: If you want to see what happens when an object starts to spin very fast, check out this video. https://youtu.be/ZpoyoPSiB3M?t=76 The same would happen to a planetary object.

Comment: As the rotation speed increases, so does the centrifugal force which tends to make things on the Equator lighter than they would be at the poles. At a rotation speed very *very* much lower than the speed of light, the centrifugal force at the Equator will become equal to the gravitational force, and then there will be nothing keeping the planet in one piece.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, worldbuilding wise? As it stands, we don't have the world context nor the artistic goals. We need these to consider the question as worldbuilding and not pure science.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If an object was to be spun at an angular velocity such that its surface even  approached the speed of light, [centrifugal forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) would tear apart any object made from real matter, and anything on its surface would likewise be flung away.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing can move at the speed of light except light as far as we know.

Nothing physical could survive spinning anywhere near the speed of light without being destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, i edited my question to say "at or near the speed of light"